# Can 64 bit data type be used as argument to AdjustWindowRect

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

`AdjustWindowRect` declared

```
BOOL WINAPI AdjustWindowRect(
  _Inout_ LPRECT lpRect,
  _In_    DWORD  dwStyle,
  _In_    BOOL   bMenu
);
```

How do I use `GetWindowLongPtr(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE)` that returns `LONG_PTR` as the second parameter to `AdjustWindowRect`?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. It looks like Microsoft thinks that window styles are and will be only 32 bits long. Therefore `AdjustWindowRect`, `AdjustWindowRectEx`, `CreateWindow`, `CreateWindowEx` and probably other functions still use a `DWORD dwStyle`.

`GetWindowLongPtr` is not only for `GWL_STYLE`, so it returns a value which is long enough to hold a LONG or a pointer. But that does not mean that the full value range is used for every type of value.

To answer your question: you can call

```
AdjustWindowRect(lpRect, GetWindowLongPtr(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE), bMenu);
```

or (with typecast)

```
AdjustWindowRect(lpRect, (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE), bMenu);
```

but you could also call

```
AdjustWindowRect(lpRect, GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE), bMenu);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: @GaneshMadhav If you like the answer please accept it and feel free to up vote it.